# Arc length measure on a level of a cone

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a cone $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}z^{2}$ and a  horisontal curve on it say at height $h$. What would be the "arc lenght expression" of this curve? (In this sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fix $z=h$, then it is just on a circle of radius $ah$. If you want to parametrize the circle, this is nothing but $\phi: [0,2 \pi] \to S$ given by $\theta \mapsto (ah \cos \theta, ah \sin \theta, h)$ 
, where $S$ is just the circle

so the arc length is

$$\int_{o}^{2 \pi}ah \,dt=2 \pi ah$$

otherwise known as the circumference of a circle with radius $ah$.

Comment: I am looking for somthing along the lies of $\mid (x \circ C)^{'}(t) \mid$

Comment: what in the world is that?

Comment: It is on the wiki page under "curve on a surface"

Comment: That's exactly what this integral is, if you want just irrelevant notation, we've taken a curve $\gamma(t)=(ah\cos(t),ah\sin(t),h)$ where $\gamma:[0,2 \pi] \to S$, and $$|\gamma^{\prime}(t)|=\sqrt{\frac{dx}{dt}^2+\frac{dy}{dt}^2+\frac{dz}{dt}^2}=\sqrt{(ah^2)[(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)]+0}=ah$$ and taking the riemann integral over the interval $[0,2 \pi]$ gives the the integral appearing in my answer.

Comment: look at the next subsection of the article, this is just polar co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The curve is at height $z=h$, so the curve is $x^2+y^2=a^2h^2$. This is a circle of radius $ah$. Its length is $2\pi ah$.